# Weird error when delivering mail : undefined method `index' for 2011-09-09 22:15:28 +0200:Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deprecated

When I deliver emails I get this weird error :

```
 Failure/Error: publication = FactoryGirl.create(:publication, :author => author)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `index' for 2011-09-09 22:15:28 +0200:Time
```

And the stack trace is not of any help.

Any idea ?

Comment: Run into same problem while upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very simple, you should NOT use :

```
default :sent_on => Time.now
```

in your mailer class.

Was tricky though :)

Comment: I had this problem when upgrading to the new `ActionMailer` convention for Rails 3, and our old emails used `sent_on` and this fixed it. To clarify, you should not use `sent_on => Time.now` AT ALL because immediately sending mail is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error when I passed (mistakenly) the :headers parameter to 
the mail method. After removing :headers (and using the headers method instead)
it worked.